# problem of methode url in java web service

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, jersey, angular5

I have a problem about web service in java and angular.
when I perform an edit operation with angular, the operation becomes an add operation. Data can't change, it's add into the table

it's my jpa (utilisateurJPA.java)

```
@Override
public void update(Utilisateur object) {
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    try {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.merge(object);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        LOGGER.error("Erreur lors de la mise à jour d'un Utilisateur");
    } finally {
        if (em.getTransaction().isActive())
            em.getTransaction().rollback();
        em.close();
    }   
}
```

it's my rest (utilisateurRest.java)

```
// Mise a jour d'un enregistrement de type utilisateur
    @Path("/update")
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void update(Utilisateur utilisateur) {
        jpa_utilisateur.update(utilisateur);
    }
```

it's my corsfilter (CorsFilter.java)

```
package com.ws.util;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.container.PreMatching;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
@PreMatching
public class CorsFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext request) throws IOException {
        if (isPreflightRequest(request)) {
            request.abortWith(Response.ok().build());
            return;
        }
    }

    private static boolean isPreflightRequest(ContainerRequestContext request) {
        return request.getHeaderString("Origin") != null
                && request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("OPTIONS");
    }

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext request, ContainerResponseContext response)
            throws IOException {
        if (request.getHeaderString("Origin") == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (isPreflightRequest(request)) {
            response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
            response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
            response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, " +
                "Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, CSRF-Token");
        }
        response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    }
}
```

it's my service in angular (utilisateurService.service.ts)

```
import { Utilisateur } from "../modeles/utilisateur";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UtilisateurService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAll(): Observable<Utilisateur[]> {
    return this.http.get<Utilisateur[]>('http://localhost:8080/Gestion_tache/tache/utilisateur/getall');
  }

  getById(id: number): Observable<Utilisateur> {
    return this.http.get<Utilisateur>('http://localhost:8080/Gestion_tache/tache/utilisateur/' + id);
  }

  add(utilisateur: Utilisateur): Observable<Utilisateur> {
    return this.http.post<Utilisateur>('http://localhost:8080/Gestion_tache/tache/utilisateur/add', utilisateur);
  }

  edit(utilisateur: Utilisateur): Observable<Utilisateur> {
    return this.http.post<Utilisateur>('http://localhost:8080/Gestion_tache/tache/utilisateur/update', utilisateur);
  }

  supp(utilisateur: Utilisateur) {
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/Gestion_tache/tache/utilisateur/delete', utilisateur);
  }
}
```

it's my edit component (editUtilisateur.component.ts)

```
edit(utilisateur) {
    this.utilisateurService.edit(utilisateur)
        .subscribe( data => {
          alert('Utilisateur modifiée');
          this.location.back();
        });
  }
```

Comment: How does your Utilisateur entity look like?

Comment: so where is the problem ... in the javax.ws code or in the JPA code? Basic debugging would tell you that.

Comment: I test this web service in postman and the result is the same as in the display with angular. I think that the problem is in java code but I don't think where is problem. the code is true but the result is not coherent

Comment: Can you PLEASE post the Utilisateur entity!

Comment: Do you save the entity with the id? If not, it will create a new one. How an update should work is that the client should make a GET request to get the entity. This entity should have all the data, including the ID. Then make your updates on the client side, and send the whole thing back.

Comment: What you should do is _lookup_ the entity first, from the id of the passed object. If it is not found, then send a 404 response. If it is found, then update _all_ the properties from the passed in one into the looked-up one. The save the looked-up one.